# setState() called in constructor, Can I change the state of a widget from another class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to change the state of the widget by defining a custom function to set state and then I'm calling that function from a new class I created.

> setState() called in constructor: _MyHomePageState#da7cc(lifecycle
>   state: created, no widget, not mounted)

**HomePage:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ed_cell/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

Widget authStatus = Text('Welcome');

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState myHomePageState= new _MyHomePageState();
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => myHomePageState;
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          height: 575,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/rocket.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'U create\nWe support',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 80, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    authStatus,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onAuthChange() {
     var x=AuthService().status;
    if (AuthService().status == 'Sucessful Sign In') {
      setState(()  {
        authStatus = Text(
          'Welcome',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 50),
        );
        print(x);
      });
      print('object'+x);
    } else {
      setState(()  {
        authStatus = RaisedButton(
          onPressed: null,
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          child: Text(
            'Join Now',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**AuthService:**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:ed_cell/home_page.dart';

class AuthService{
  String status;

  signIn(email,password){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then((user){
      print('Signed In '+user.user.uid);
      status='Sucessful Sign In';
    }).catchError((e){
      status='Failure in Sign In';
      print(e);
    });
    MyHomePage().myHomePageState.onAuthChange();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error relates to `HomePage` not being inserted into the widget tree yet. You can call `setState` from another class as you have already done correctly, but the `HomePage` widget has to be somewhere already in the widget tree for it to be able to do `setState`.